# Condition compiling with multiple declarations?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I have 3 projects which is depending on the same shared library.

There is a singleton class inside the library which is providing globally shared objects across the project, anyway this globally shared objects is instances of a classes, which is different, depending on the platform, for instance :

on mobile application:

```
public static var message : TMobileMessage;
```

on desktop application:

```
public static var message : TDesktopMessage;
```

on web applcation:

```
public static var message : TWebApplication;
```

- How to implement condition compiling on declarations, since the follow code doesn't works :

  ```
  If( CONFIG::applicationType == 'mobile' )
      public static var message : TMobileMessage;
  else
     If( CONFIG::applicationType == 'desktop' )
         public static var message : TDesktopMessage;
     else
         If( CONFIG::applicationType == 'web' )
             public static var message : TWebApplication;
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following.

1. Use conditional compiler's declarations like this:

   CONFIG::MOBILE {
       public static var message : TMobileMessage;
   }

   CONFIG::DESKTOP {
       public static var message : TDesktopMessage;
   }

   CONFIG::WEB {
       public static var message : TWebApplication;
   }
2. Create a flex-config.xml for each of the configs. Declare these conditionals in each of the config.xml:

**flex-config-mobile.xml**

```
<compiler>
        <define>
            <name>CONFIG::MOBILE</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </define>
        <define>
            <name>CONFIG::DESKTOP</name>
            <value>false</value>
        </define>
        <define>
            <name>CONFIG::WEB</name>
            <value>false</value>
        </define>
</compiler>
```

**flex-config-desktop.xml**

```
<compiler>

        <define>
            <name>CONFIG::MOBILE</name>
            <value>false</value>
        </define>
        <define>
            <name>CONFIG::DESKTOP</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </define>
        <define>
            <name>CONFIG::WEB</name>
            <value>false</value>
        </define>

</compiler>
```

**flex-config-web.xml**

```
<compiler>

        <define>
            <name>CONFIG::MOBILE</name>
            <value>false</value>
        </define>
        <define>
            <name>CONFIG::DESKTOP</name>
            <value>false</value>
        </define>
        <define>
            <name>CONFIG::WEB</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </define>

</compiler>
```

1. Use the appropriate flex-config in a build script or your IDE.

Comment: isn't this overly complicated?

Answer (score 1):

if you define the CONFIG as a compiler argument, or moify flex_config.xml, you can use the following:

( TDesktopMessage, TMobileMessage, etc should extend IMessage or whatever you want.)

```
public static var message:IMessage;


CONFIG::mobile
{
  msg = "mobile"; //or msg = messages[mobile] or however you want to declare
}

CONFIG::desktop
{
  msg = "desktop";
}

CONFIG::web
{
  msg = "web";
}
```

Comment: also, do you need to config it? if you use flash.system.Capabilities.version you can stringcompare it to iOS, And (roid), mac, lnx, win, etc.. and then use normal as3 if-s. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#

Comment: if you try to compile it directly - it might involve classes which is not supported on the platform - like MX classes on mobile, anyway using interface is interesting idea, which could increase a bit the codebase, but would rise the readability. It is generally a good idea. Thanks! :)